# Кодировка в contains?

Tags: jquery, python, кодировка

```
$('p:contains(u"Время работы")')
```

**'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 29**

Использую данный код в скрипте Python для парса, использовал несколько методов, но все напрасно.

Comment: Вы используете jquery в скрипте на python?

Comment: если точнее, то библиотеку pyquery   

    g =Grab()
    .....
    worktime = g.pyquery('p:contains(u"Время работы")').text()

Comment: Тогда, скорей всего, запись должна выглядеть так:

    $(u"p:contains('Время работы')")

Comment: Спасибо, ответ был совсем рядом

Answer (score 1):

Из предложенного **@LinnTroll**:

> Запись должна выглядеть так: $(u"p:contains('Время работы')")